# Grub not recognizing Windows 8.1 partition after swapping notebooks

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi, bios

I took an existing dual booting disk from an UEFI Acer A5 notebook and swapped it into Acer One with BIOS. I can boot to Ubuntu 16.04 just fine but not into Windows 8.1.

```
:~$ sudo gdisk /dev/sda
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.1
```

Partition table scan:

```
MBR: protective  
BSD: not present  
APM: not present  
GPT: present
```

Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.

```
~$ sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL
[sudo] password for: 
NAME   FSTYPE   SIZE MOUNTPOINT LABEL
sda           465.8G            
├─sda4 ntfs   221.9G            Acer
├─sda2 vfat     300M            ESP
├─sda7 swap    20.9G [SWAP]     
├─sda5 ntfs     450M            
├─sda3          128M            
├─sda1 ntfs     400M            Recovery
├─sda8 ntfs    15.3G            Push Button Reset
└─sda6 ext4   206.5G /
```

Comment: the new computer has EFI boot? what error do you get? Note: swapping computers will cause Windows Genuine Advantage to invalidate your key

Comment: The current computer has BIOS. Grub does not see the windows partition. I used super-grub-disk to get the computer booting first time. SGD sees the windows os but requires UEFI boot.

Comment: Disk /dev/sda: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt

Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048    821247    819200   400M unknown
/dev/sda2     821248   1435647    614400   300M EFI System
/dev/sda3    1435648   1697791    262144   128M BIOS boot
/dev/sda4    1697792 466947907 465250116 221.9G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda5  466948096 467869695    921600   450M Windows recovery

Comment: /dev/sda6  467869696 900894719 433025024 206.5G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda7  900894720 944769023  43874304  20.9G Linux swap
/dev/sda8  944769024 976773119  32004096  15.3G unknown

Answer (score 0):

As you stated in comments, Windows is UEFI the computer is Legacy only.
This means that windows will not boot in this computer unless you reinstall windows in Legacy mode. The same is true of Grub that is why you had to use super grub disk to boot ubuntu.